# Is there an algebraic non-rational extension of the integers, whose set of prime elements contains the prime integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, prime-numbers

Let the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ with $\alpha$ an algebraic number.
Let $P(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])$ be the set of all the [prime elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

*Question*: Is there $\alpha$ algebraic and non-rational such that $P(\mathbb{Z}) \subset P(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])$?

Comment: My intuition is that no, there isn't. Given primes $p, q$, observe how these factorize in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{pq}]$ when that is a UFD. Of course many rings are not UFDs.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: what do you think of the answer of Moos?

Comment: It looks good but it's way over my head. I know next to nothing about morphisms.

Comment: I posted a follow-up here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1194088/1778

Comment: By prime elements, do you mean they must be prime or is it acceptable if they're irreducible? e.g., in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$, $2, 3, 5$ are irreducible but not prime. Also, does the algebraic number have to be real or can it be imaginary or complex?

Comment: See also this related but different question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174253/given-h-mathcalo-mathbbq-sqrtd-1-what-is-the-longest-possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f \in \mathbb Z[X]$ be the (maybe non-monic, but definitely primitive) minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. We can assume the leading coefficient to be positive.

Consider the homomorphism $\mathbb Z[X] \to \mathbb Z[\alpha], X \mapsto \alpha$. The kernel is a non-maximal prime ideal containing $f$, hence it is equal to $(f)$, since $(f)$ is a prime-ideal (f is irreducible since it is primitive and irreducible over $\mathbb Q$) and any prime ideal properly containing $(f)$ is maximal. We deduce $\mathbb Z[\alpha] \cong \mathbb Z[X]/(f)$.

Pick $x \in \mathbb Z$ suitable large, such that $f(x) > 1$. In particular there is a prime $p$ with $p|f(x)$. We compute

$$\mathbb Z[\alpha]/(p) \cong \mathbb Z[X]/(f,p) \cong \mathbb F_p[X]/(f)$$

The latter is no integral domain, since $f(x) = 0$ in $\mathbb F_p$, in particular $f$ is not irreducible.

Comment: Is it a proof by contradiction? If so, where exactly do you use that $α$ is algebraic non-rational and $P(\mathbb{Z}) \subset P(\mathbb{Z[\alpha]})$

Comment: I use that it has a mininal polynomial of degree at least two...thats the same as saying algebraic non-rational. Furthermore I show the existence of a prime integer, that is not prime in $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$. It is not really a typical proof by contradiction.

Comment: Where do you use that the polynomial is of degree at least two? Why the kernel is non-maximal?

Comment: You should give yourself some thoughts on the details....Well: I state that the polynomial is reducible mod $p$ since it has a root. Works only for degree at least two. The kernel is not maximal since the image is not a field.

Comment: It's not a proof by contradiction, but a proof by intimidation... :) I'm sorry I do not practice commutative ring since more than 10 years, I'm rusty, and so it will be a bit long for me for checking an answer without all the details.

Comment: Nice argument! Is it a well-known result? Did you ever see it in a classical book?

Comment: To be honest, i have never seen this question/result before. But I have never read any textbook on algebraic number theory. I am pretty sure this argument has been given somewhere.