# Least rational prime which is composite in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, prime-numbers, extension-field, integer-rings

Sébastien Palcoux [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1192876/1778) if there was some irrational algebraic $\alpha$ such that all rational primes are primes in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha].$ MooS [answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1192925/1778) that there are no such $\alpha.$ This leads to a natural question:

> Given some irrational algebraic $\alpha,$ what is the least rational prime $p$ such that $p$ is composite in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$?

I'm looking for an upper bound on $p$. (I wasn't able to extract one from MooS' proof -- it can be greater than $f(x)$.)

Probably this question would work better in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)}$ than $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$; feel free to use whichever is more convenient.

Comment: Well-known example (Gaussian integer): for $\alpha = i$ then $p=2=(1-i)(1+i)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial result is the following:

For any finite set $\{p_1, \dotsc, p_s\}$ of prime numbers, there exists an algebraic irrational number $\alpha$ such that all $p_i$ are prime in $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$.

To that account, it suffices to show: There is a polynomial in $\mathbb Z[x]$ of degree at least $2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb F_{p_i}$ for all $i$ and irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.

We proceed by induction on $s$, the case $s=1$ being the equivalent to the statement, that $\mathbb F_p$ is not algebraically closed.

Let (exists by induction hypothesis) $f \in \mathbb Z[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ which is irreducible modulo $p_i$ for $1\leq i \leq s-1$. Let $P = p_1 \dotsb p_{s-1}$. $P$ is coprime to $p_s$, hence there is $Q \in \mathbb Z$ with $PQ=1 \mod {p_s}$

Let $g \in \mathbb Z[x]$ be a monic polynomial of degree greater than $n$, which is irreducible modulo $p_s$. Consider $$h := f + P(g-Qf)$$

Modulo $p_i, 1\leq i \leq s-1$, we obtain $h = f$, hence irreducible.

Modulo $p_s$, we obtain $h = Pg$, hence irreducible.

Furthermore, the leading coefficient of $h$ is $P$, hence co-prime to $p_s$. So the irreducibility in $\mathbb Z[x]$ follows from the irreducibility in $\mathbb F_{p_s}$.

---

This result shows, that there is no global upper bound. So the upper bound depends on $\alpha$. If you ask about being prime, the answer is just the least prime, that occurs among the the prime factors of $f(x)$, while $x$ runs through $\mathbb Z$ and $f$ is the minimal polynomial.

If you ask about being irreducible (which I guess you do), the question might be better investigated in $\mathcal O_{\mathbb Q(\alpha)}$. It comes down to the question which is the least prime among the norms of elements of that ring. But I cannot think any further.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But the prime factors among $f(x)$ don't all work. For example, 2 is prime even in the Eisenstein integers, let alone $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. But with $f(x)=x^2+3$, $f(1)=4$ (which 2 divides).

Comment: You should rethink about that. Indeed $2$ is prime in the Eisenstein integers, but $2$ is not prime in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$. We have $$2 | (1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})$$ but $2$ does not divide one of the factors. This does not work in the Eisenstein integers, since $2$ actually divides $1+\sqrt{-3}$ in that ring.

This corresponds to the fact, that $x^2+x+1$ (minimal polynomial of the generator of the Eisenstein integers) is irreducible mod $2$, but $x^2+3$ is not. So this is no counterexample to my arguments, actually it shomehow confirms the thoughts.

Comment: Hmm, I'm going to have to think about that. Thanks!